# solr indexing strategy

Tags: solr

We have millions of documents in mongo we are looking to index on solr. Obviously when we do this the first time we need to index all the documents.

But after that, we should only need to index the documents as they change. What is the best way to do this? Should we call addDocument and then in cron call commit()? What does addDocument vs commit vs optimize do (I am using Apache_Solr_Service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Solr 3.x you can [forget the optimize](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/simon-says%3a-optimize-is-bad-for-you), which merges all segments into one big segment. The commit makes changes visible to new IndexReaders; it's expensive, I wouldn't call it for each document you add. Instead of calling it through a cron, I'd use the [autocommit](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Update_Handler_Section) in `solrconfig.xml`. You can tune the value depending on how much time you can wait to get new documents while searching.

Comment: What would you do to determine if a document needs to be indexed? Would you set a flag on the mongo document needs_index?

Answer (score 0):

The document won't actually be added to the index until you do commit() - it could be rolled back. optimize() will (ostensibly; I've not had particularly good luck with it) reduce the size of the index (documents that have been deleted still take up room unless the index is optimized).

Answer (score 0):

If you set autocommit for your database, then you can be sure that any documents added to the database via update, have been committed, when the autocommit interval has passed. I have used a 5-minute interval and it works fine even when a few thousand updates happen within the 5 minutes. After a full reindex is complete, I wait 5 minutes and then tell people that it is done. In fact, when people ask how quickly updates get into the db, I will tell them that we poll for changes every minute, but that there are variables (such as a sudden big batch) and it is best to not expect things to be updated for 5 or 6 minutes. So far, nobody has really claimed a business need to have it update faster than that.

This is with a 350,000 record db totalling roughly 10G in RAM.